# error: conflicting declaration - cant a pointer be an int?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile a library, when running `make` I get many of the following errors:

```
error: conflicting declaration ‘int x’
error: ‘x’ has a previous declaration as ‘Text* x’
```

Here is the code:

```
.
.
.
class Text;
class Code {

    private:
            std::vector<std::string> *tokens;
            std::vector<std::string> *compounds;
            std::vector<std::string> *compound_xml;
            std::vector<std::string> *compound_xml_action;
            void set_helper(Text *x, int a, int b, int c, std::string field, std::string value);
            std::string itoa(int x);

    public:
            Code();
            ~Code();

            int analyse_code(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
            int print(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
            int is_class(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
            int is_class2(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
            int not_class(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);

 .
 .
 .
```

so in `analyse_code` function\method, should I convert `int x` to `int a` or `int wtv` or is it smth else causing the error?

since the author of the library has used `Text* x` and `int x` in many functions, I thought maybe he knows what he's doing and pointers can be `int`, or am I wrong thinking he knows what he is doing?

Irrelevant: The library is Adso, a Chinese text analysis engine.

Comment: You wrong thinking he knows what he doing. The error says conflicting declarations, that's never right.

Comment: so I should change `int x` to `int smth` then, right?

Comment: Hmm. The library code is essentially full of bugs and generally horrible. The author seems to be writing it blind, without checking whether it actually compiles, and he generally seems to have no idea what he’s actually doing. Don’t use it.

Comment: I would change `Text* x` to `Text* text`.

Comment: To add to what Konrad says. Not only buggy, but also written by someone who only has limited understanding of C++.

Comment: I get many of the same errors in other classes, unfortunately I have to use it though, since that was the only Chinese to pinyin  library in C++ I could find... but thanks anyhow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two parameters named 'x' in declaration like that:

```
int not_class(Text *x, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
```

Name one of them something else. For example:

```
int not_class(Text *txt, std::string c, int x, int y, int z);
```

The author was not very good, so beware other errors too.

Comment: yes, seems he was drunk writing it, cause I get `error: ‘strcmp’ was not declared in this scope` since he hasn't include `<cstring>`... but thanks for your answer... I will accept your answer in a minute, when I'm allowed to... cheers

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not only in `analyse_code` but in all the private functions. if you have the source code (.c file) I would have check it there also.

anyway you should change the `Text *x` to anything else such as `Text *text`

Comment: It’s also in the source files. And it pervades the code base apparently. But this is just one of many problems in the code …

Comment: if the code is so badly written, i may want to try finding another library to use.