# Transliterate CJK to Latin -- preferably in C++

Tags: c++, cjk, icu, transliteration

I am trying to write a program that can transliterate CJK to Latin (i.e Pinyin, Romaji, etc.). For example you give a Chinese, Japanese or Korean document as input and then you get the transliterated version into Latin as output.

I am new in this field so please bear with me here.

Obviously, first I need to detect the type of the language (Chinese, Japanese or Korean) before getting any further. Then, as I understood so far, in order to do the transliteration, I need to divide the text  into words, since in these languages there is no *space* between words. This is called [word segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_segmentation#Word_segmentation). Finally after finding out the words I need to transliterate them into Latin.

So here is my question:

1. There are lots of (well not really! Better say some) libraries that do the transliteration job, since I'm looking for open source ones in C/C++, I found Adson (only for Chinese) and ICU4C. Cloned Git repo from Adson [didn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439914/error-conflicting-declaration-cant-a-pointer-be-an-int). And I was not able to find simple, straight forward tutorial for ICU4C. How can I find some tutorial on ICU4C usage? Do you know any other library to transliterate CJK to Latin? If the accuracy ratio is higher(~90%), I can forget about it being written in C++.

Comment: For Korean it's quite simple since they don't use Chinese characters anymore. I have Python and Javascript code that you could translate to C(++) if you wish.

Comment: Also, Korean *uses* whitespace, spaces are just as important in Korean as in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICU: there are examples in http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general and ICU 50 now has CJK word segmentation. The `uconv` sample can be used with something like `uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x 'Any-Latin'`  to go through Any-Latin transform. That doesn't take language into account, though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through the link you posted, but do you have any suggestion/thought on how I can detect what language is what?

Comment: See the closures - you should separate your question into multiple questions. No short answers on language detection— need a corpus and/or specialized code. Impossible to guess the right answer for a short string like "三" for example - is it "yī" or "san" or something else?